# Macro to replace an identifier in its argument

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need a macro that replaces one identifier with another in the code passed to it as an argument. To solve my task it is sufficient to define REPLACE_X_WITH_Y so that this code compiles:

```
#define REPLACE_X_WITH_Y(...) __VA_ARGS__ //TODO: replace x with y
int main()
{
    REPLACE_X_WITH_Y(
        int x = 5;
        x = 0;
    );
    return y;
}
```

However, it would be better to have a generic macro REPLACE:

```
#define REPLACE(x, y, ...) __VA_ARGS__ //TODO: replace x with y
int main()
{
    REPLACE(x, y,
        int x = 5;
        x = 0;
    );
    return y;
}
```

Is any of these macros possible with C++ preprocessor?

My actual use case is the emulation of concepts for one particular case on older compilers:

```
#define REQUIRES(...) template<class T_=T, enable_if_t<REPLACE_T_WITH_T_(__VA_ARGS__), int>* = nullptr>

template<typename T> struct S
{
    REQUIRES(is_integral_v<T>) int f(T x) {return 0;}
    REQUIRES(is_floating_point_v<T>) int f(T x) {return 1;}
};
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What's your target version? C++14?

Comment: Either you pass your code to that macro or to your compiler and use the simple swap function

Comment: I haven't decided yet, it may be C++14 or higher. For now I would prefer a C++14 compatible solution. Is there any difference for preprocessor? @Ardent Coder, I don't understand, what do you mean about passing my code to the compiler? What swap function?

Comment: I would use a `static_assert` here. I don't think `REPLACE_X_WITH_Y` is possible to implement.

Comment: @devoln I simply meant that writing a macro to handle explicit code is similar to writing a compiler inside that macro lol, but for a tiny case anyways. Please note that I won't be notified if you use spaces inside the @-notation

Comment: This doesn't seem possible but perhaps you can do it [this way](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KZmqfCsNKWFQx86w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to perform such an involved operation, but in your particular case you don't need it. You need a dependent context for SFINAE, but it can very well just embark your condition as-is, and tie it to a dependent bit over which you have control:

```
template <class, bool Value>
struct dependent_bool
: std::integral_constant<bool, Value> { };

#define REQUIRES(...)                                       \
    template<                                               \
        class Require_T = void,                             \
        ::std::enable_if_t<                                 \
            dependent_bool<Require_T, (__VA_ARGS__)>::value,\
            int                                             \
        >* = nullptr                                        \
    >
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MFADirp0AuEYAYfm)